# get script Jquery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

im having troubles with getting script from another file in jquery.
i've tried with $.getScript and $.ajax();
how can i include one script like require.js in jquery?

**util.js**

```
 function getSessionInformation () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../controller/controller.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    data: {
      action: 'getInfoCompany'
    },
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    try{
      return data;
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  });
}
```

**file.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        _getAllUsers();
    });
    function _getAllUsers()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "util.js",
          dataType: "script",
          cache: true
        }).done(function() {
            alert("im in");
            jQuery.cookie("cookie_name", "value", { expires: 7 });
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can't `return` something from an async action.

Comment: also I've been tried return an alert but neither work

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/projectDashboard/view/util.js" . the both files is placed in the same path "js/"

Answer (score 0):

Try again, the [`getScript` method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) is the right tool for this:

```
function _getAllUsers()
{
    jQuery.getScript("util.js", function() {
        alert("im in");
        jQuery.cookie("cookie_name", "value", { expires: 7 });
    });
}
```

#### Update:

The reason that you get a HTTP 404 error is that the URL that you are using will look for the script in the same folder as the page. You need a `../` to get out of the `view` folder and a `js` to get into the script folder:

```
jQuery.getScript("../js/util.js", function() {
```